# Getting "mismatched input '>' expecting {<EOF>, IDENTIFICATION, REPLACE}" when trying to run COBOL code

Tags: cobol

COMPLETE NOOB here just trying to learn some COBOL. I'm following a YT video and the code I have written verbatim just won't run because of this error. Do I need to install another extension?

```
       >>SOURCE FORMAT FREE

IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. coboltut.
AUTHOR. John Doe.
DATE-WRITTEN. November 24th 2021
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 UserName PIC X(30) VALUE "You".
01 Num1    PIC 9 VALUE ZEROS.
01 Num2    PIC 9 VALUE ZEROS.
01 Total PIC 99 VALUE 0.
01 SSNum.
       02 SSArea   PIC 999
       03 SSGroup  PIC 99
       03 SSSerial PIC 9999

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
DISPLAY "WHAT IS YOUR NAME " WITH NO ADVANCING
ACCEPT UserName
DISPLAY "Hello " USERNAME





STOP RUN.
```

Comment: What error message do you get ???

Comment: Which compiler are you using? It appears to be an older compiler that does not recognize the `SOURCE FORMAT` directive. You could place an asterisk (`*`) in column 7 of the directive and add 7 spaces to the beginning of each source line. That should allow the program to compile with an older compiler.

Comment: Note: you don't **run** the COBOL code but get an error before. likike during **compile**,

Not sure what "extension" you reference, _maybe_ you are on vscode and _maybe_ you get a message from an extension that can't parse that so _maybe_ you don't even compile?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$ cat coboltut.cbl 
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. coboltut.
AUTHOR. John Doe.
DATE-WRITTEN. November 24th 2021

ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.

DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 UserName PIC X(30) VALUE "You".
01 Num1    PIC 9 VALUE ZEROS.
01 Num2    PIC 9 VALUE ZEROS.
01 Total   PIC 99 VALUE ZEROS.
01 SSNum.
       03 SSArea   PIC 999.
       03 SSGroup  PIC 99.
       03 SSSerial PIC 9999.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
DISPLAY "WHAT IS YOUR NAME " WITH NO ADVANCING
ACCEPT UserName
DISPLAY "Hello " USERNAME
STOP RUN.
```

Execution:

```
$ cobc -F -x coboltut.cbl 
$ ./coboltut
WHAT IS YOUR NAME Halley
Hello Halley
```